# Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{k} \left(n+i\right)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Original question is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{k} \left(n+i\right)}$$
I got it down to $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)!}{(k+n)!}$$
Here I am confused.  Possible fraction decomposition but its ugly!  Maybe this approach is not good?  Ideas?

Answer is $$\frac{1}{k \cdot k!}$$
I want to know how to proceed with my work though

Comment: I think either there is a typo, or you are confused.  Note that $$\prod_{i=0}^k\,(n+1)=(n+1)^{k+1}\,.$$  Did you perhaps want to write $$\prod_{i=0}^k\,(n+{\color{red}{i}}+1)=\frac{(n+k+1)!}{n!}\,?$$

Comment: Batominovski may be correct that there is an error. As written, the second sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n! /(k+1+n)!$ converges to $((k+1)(k+1)!)^{-1}$; see https://oeis.org/A177262

Comment: @Batominovski Yes I meant $i$ not $1$ in the product! Thanks

Comment: @Integrand Yes, thats correct but can you explain how?  This is a no calculator/resource question

Comment: Do you want the way or is the solution enough? Because I found the exact solution for each $k$..

Comment: @thinkingeye what is "the way" verse "the solution" ???

Comment: With "way", I mean the proof.

Comment: Solution is enough I think

Comment: Ah. I see, you already edited and have an answer...(well, that answer I wanted to give)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summation of the reciprocals of the product of consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417844/summation-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-product-of-consecutive-integers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k+n)!}
&= \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!(n-1)!}{(k+n)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \beta(k+1,n)\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 t^k(1-t)^{n-1}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1 t^k\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-t)^{n-1}\bigg)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1 \frac{t^k}{t}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{k \cdot k!}
\end{align*}

Here, $\beta(\cdot,\cdot)$ is beta function.

Answer (score 3):

For $k\ge 0$, and $n\ge 1$, let
$$
A_k(n)=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k}(n+i)}\ .
$$
Then
$$
A_k(n+1)-A_k(n)=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k}(n+1+i)}-
\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k}(n+i)}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}(n+i)}-\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k}(n+i)}
$$
by shifting the index in the first product. Then by factoring out the common factors
$$
A_k(n+1)-A_k(n)=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(n+i)}
\times\left[\frac{1}{n+k+1}-\frac{1}{n}\right]
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(n+i)}
\times\left[\frac{-(k+1)}{n(n+k+1)}\right]\ .
$$
So
$$
A_k(n+1)-A_k(n)=-(k+1)A_{k+1}(n)\ .
$$
Now the wanted series can be computed by telescoping, for $k\ge 1$,
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_k(n)=\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[
A_{k-1}(n)-A_{k-1}(n+1)
\right]=\frac{A_{k-1}(1)}{k}=\frac{1}{k\times k!}\ .
$$

**Remark:**
The key identity $A_{k-1}(n+1)-A_{k-1}(n)=-k A_{k+1}(n)$ is the discrete analogue of $\frac{d}{dx}x^{-k}=-k x^{-k-1}$. The same kind of argument also works for the products in the numerators. This actually gives a way of computing sums of powers $\sum_{n=1}^{N}n^k$, by changing the linear basis to that of rising powers. This involves the Stirling numbers.

Comment: $A_{k-1}(1)=1/k!$, whence the final answer is $1/(k \cdot k!)$.

Comment: sorry typo fixed

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+k)} &= \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k}{n(n+1)...(n+k)} \\
 &= \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)...(n+k)} \right], \\
\end{align*}

and [this series telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) so that every minus cancels with a plus, and we are left with only the first plus term, when $n = 1$:

$$\frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{1(1+1)...(1+k-1)} = \frac{1}{k * k!}$$